# I have infinite loop from <jsp:forward page="/myservlet" /> when submit input is clicked

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

**My jsp page** web/jspPages/addReport.jsp

```
<%if(request.getParameter("addReport") != null){ %>
<jsp:forward page="/addReportGuiControlServlet" />
<%} %>

<form action="addReport.jsp" name="myform" method="POST">
    <h4 class="desc">How many people are there in the queue?</h4>
    <div>   
        <input class="addreport" type="checkbox" id="isLast" name="isLast">
        <label class="desc">I'm the last of the queue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
        <input class="addreport" type="text" name="queueLen" id="queueLen" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="container2">    
        <input class="addreport" type="submit" name="addReport" value="Add Report">
    </div>
</form>
```

**my servlet**

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
{
    
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jspPages/addReport.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

**My web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddReportGuiControlServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>logic.boundary.web.controlgrafico.AddReportGuiControlServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddReportGuiControlServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addReportGuiControlServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The error that result is a infinite loop. I think the problem is the parameter "addReport" because in the the servlet i try to print it and is != null, but i didn't know how to set this value.

Comment: Hi why you have `<%if(request.getParameter("addReport") != ..` in your `addReport.jsp` page ? why not simply give servlet url in your form action ?

Comment: Because I need to pass another information that there are in the jsp. My idea is to fill a bean with all this information and then forward to the servlet

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by adding a parameter to the URL into the Servlet:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jspPages/addReport.jsp?forward=true");
```

Then I insert control into JSP:

```
<%if(request.getParameter("addReport") != null){
    //controllo se la pagina è stata già mandata dalla servlet

    if(request.getParameter("forward") == null){
    %>
        <jsp:forward page="/addReportGuiControlServlet"></jsp:forward>
    <%
    }
}
%>
```

This because the parameter addReport remain not null then the forward by the Servlet